# Translating camera with radius/diameter instead of x,y,z?

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, translate, radius

So I have this example as shown below and I was wondering if its possible to translate a camera by changing the radius & diameter instead of using x,y,z positions (Vector). For now im using a cube but I want to add a second camera basically.

[image]

Since I know where 0,0,0 (origin) is, is there any way to translate the cube by setting diameter radius or whatever is required and also lock it on the origin?

What I use to move the Cube (Three.js)

```
var posX,posY,posZ;
var scene, camera, render;
var cubeMesh,cube_Geometry, cube_Material;

class myWorld{
    /* ... Setup World ... */
    //excecute cube();
    /* ... Set/Get positions (xyz) ... */

    cube(){
        cube_Geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20);
        cube_Material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        cube_Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cube_Geometry, cube_Material);
        cube_Mesh.position.set(0, 100, 100);
        scene.add(cube_Mesh);
    }

    animate(){ //loop function
        //THREE.Mesh.position.set (Three.js)
        cube_Mesh.position.set(posX, posY, posZ);
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Also this shouldn't be **below 0** on the **Y Axis**. Its better to leave it out in this case

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the radius and diameter"?

Comment: I have updated my question for u. But it might have to be with **cos & sin**. Not a math guy

Comment: It seems you want to update location according to polar coordinates

Comment: okay ill have a look tomorrow and i let u know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Spherical`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Spherical) and [`setFromSpherical`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Vector3.setFromSpherical):

```
var r = 10;
var theta = 310 * (Math.PI / 180); /// 310 degree to radians

var sphericalPos = new THREE.Spherical(r, 0, theta);
cube_Mesh.position.setFromSpherical(sphericalPos);
// or just do cube_Mesh.position.setFromSphericalCoords(radius, phi, theta)
```

> **Spherical(radius: Float, phi: Float, theta : Float)**
>
> - radius - the radius, or the Euclidean distance (straight-line distance) from the point to the origin. Default is 1.0.
> - phi - polar angle from the y (up) axis. Default is 0.
> - theta - equator angle around the y (up) axis. Default is 0.
>
> The poles (phi) are at the positive and negative y axis. The equator (theta) starts at positive z.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 

This works great for me if I use `THREE.Spherical(camera_RT_Radius, theta, 0)` as shown in the [GIF](https://ibb.co/Qkv5r8L).  But not on the axis I want. Notice that the 3rd slider is doing nothing for now and i want the cube to rotate on Y axis (around the house).

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou `theta`, the last parameter will rotate around y (up) axis.